# Hyperledger fabric network configuration related

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are creating a new Blockchain network using Hyperledger Fabric for our new Project.We could not able to understand which  point configtx.yaml file will be used and how the same is being accessed during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`configtx.yaml` is only used to generate a channel's genesis block based on some initial channel configuration. It is not used at runtime. The runtime channel configuration is stored on the channel's ledger based on the genesis block and any subsequent channel configuration updates.

See [Creating the network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/network/network.html#creating-the-network) for an overview of the key concepts.

See [Generate the genesis block](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html) for additional details.